# Having difficulty setting up a loop to continue program when wrong user input is entered

Tags: python

I am fairly new to programming and Python and I am struggling with setting up a loop to continue this basic name generator when user input is incorrect.  I tried researching this issue but usually find answers using integers and the like and am having difficulty translating examples to execute what I need the program to do.  I am not quite sure if my using of the IF, ELSE, and ELIF, statements is even being used correctly.  Thanks to anyone who can lend guidance on this topic.

```
import random


def orcName():
    # This is where the program will ask for male or female input from user.
    sex = input("What's your sex? ")


    # If user chooses Male the program will execute.
    if sex == 'Male':

        # This is where the list of male first names are stored.
        firstNameMale = ['Ughash', 'Spoguk', 'Truigig', 'Wudhagh', 'Wumkbanok', 'Hogug', 'Karrhig', 'Pargu',
                             'Xokuk', 'Furbog']

        # This is where the list of male last names are stored.
        lastNameMale = ['Opkagut', 'Zombilge', 'Grushnag', 'Gujarek', 'Igmut', 'Gorgo', 'Filge', 'XorokuShamob',
                            'Zurgha']
        # This is where the random function calls on the lists to assemble the name.
        firstName = random.choice(firstNameMale)
        lastName = random.choice(lastNameMale)
        print('Your name is', firstName, lastName)
        break

    # If user chooses Female the program will execute.
    elif sex == "Female":
            # This is where the list of female first names are stored.
        firstNameFemale = ['Ughash', 'Spoguk', 'Truigig', 'Wudhagh', 'Wumkbanok', 'Hogug', 'Karrhig', 'Pargu',
                               'Xokuk',
                               'Furbog']
        # This is where the list of female last names are stored.
        lastNameFemale = ['Opkagut', 'Zombilge', 'Grushnag', 'Gujarek', 'Igmut', 'Gorgo', 'Filge', 'XorokuShamob',
                              'Zurgha']
        # This is where the random function calls on the lists to assemble the name.
        firstName = random.choice(firstNameFemale)
        lastName = random.choice(lastNameFemale)
        print('Your name is', firstName, lastName)
        break

    # If user did not choose Male of Female program will execute.
    else:
        print('Please choose from Male or Female.  Remember capitalization counts!')
        break

orcName()
```

Comment: `Please choose from Male or Female. Remember capitalization counts` what a perfect example of extremely bad UX...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: I don't think you need `break` statement since there is no `loop` in the function. It gives `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`, removing `break` statements makes the code run fine, can you try that?

Comment: unrelated: `break` doesn't do anything here, and the names are the exact same for both gender inputs

Comment: Im aware, I had tried to set up a loop previously and that is why those are still there.  Just an oversight on my part before posting.  I want to set up a proper loop though, so that the program repeats if the user input doesn't match the conditions and I cant seem to set it up correctly.

Comment: The names can be changed later to better reflect the sexes.  This is just to practice and maybe create something functional for myself.

Comment: I think I read question wrong, below answers may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `raw_input` if you use python 2.

Anyway if I get what you wanna do, this should look like the basic starting main program:

```
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello, world")

    while 1:
        sex = raw_input("What's your sex? ")

        # If user chooses Male the program will execute.
        if sex == 'Male':

            # This is where the list of male first names are stored.
            firstNameMale = ['Ughash', 'Spoguk', 'Truigig', 'Wudhagh', 'Wumkbanok', 'Hogug', 'Karrhig', 'Pargu',
                             'Xokuk', 'Furbog']

            # This is where the list of male last names are stored.
            lastNameMale = ['Opkagut', 'Zombilge', 'Grushnag', 'Gujarek', 'Igmut', 'Gorgo', 'Filge', 'XorokuShamob',
                            'Zurgha']
            # This is where the random function calls on the lists to assemble the name.
            firstName = random.choice(firstNameMale)
            lastName = random.choice(lastNameMale)
            print('Your name is ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName)
            break

        # If user chooses Female the program will execute.
        elif sex == "Female":
            # This is where the list of female first names are stored.
            firstNameFemale = ['Ughash', 'Spoguk', 'Truigig', 'Wudhagh', 'Wumkbanok', 'Hogug', 'Karrhig', 'Pargu',
                               'Xokuk',
                               'Furbog']
            # This is where the list of female last names are stored.
            lastNameFemale = ['Opkagut', 'Zombilge', 'Grushnag', 'Gujarek', 'Igmut', 'Gorgo', 'Filge', 'XorokuShamob',
                              'Zurgha']
            # This is where the random function calls on the lists to assemble the name.
            firstName = random.choice(firstNameFemale)
            lastName = random.choice(lastNameFemale)
            print('Your name is ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName)
            break

        # If user did not choose Male of Female program will execute.
        else:
            print('Please choose from Male or Female.  Remember capitalization counts!')
```

Here I made an infinite loop until you enter Male or Female. Hope it helps.

Comment: Any new python development should be using python 3, so not sure if raw_input helps

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  You all helped and I can see where my code could be set up in a more logical way.  I restructured it following your guys' guidance and its working how I wanted.